# Properly handling nested resources in ASP.net MVC 4 WebApi routing

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to provide REST API in this way:

```
GET /api/devices
POST /api/devices
PUT /api/devices/1
DELETE /api/devices/1
```

This is my configuration:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And these are the actions:

```
public IEnumerable<Device> Get()
{
//return all devices
}

public Devices Get(id)
{
//return a specific devices
}
```

and so on.

The issue appears when I want to handle nested resources:

```
GET /api/devices/1/readings
POST /api/devices/1/readings
GET /api/devices/1/readings/1
PUT /api/devices/1/readings/1
DELETE /api/devices/1/readings/1
```

This is my configration for these:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "NestedApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{parentResourceId}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

The issue shows up when trying to GET and POST to the nested resource:

```
[HttpGet]
public String Readings(int parentResourceId)
{
   //return a list of readings for the device
}

[HttpPost]
public String Readings(int parentResourceId)
{
    //create and return the id of a reading for the device
}
```

This is, of course, failing because there are two actions with the same signature.

I'd like to hear from a way of accomplishing this with the most RESTful approach

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10783946/326110 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594671/nested-resources-in-asp-net-mvc-4-webapi/16094056#16094056

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft is adding Attribute Routing to increase the flexibility of the routing system.
Have a look at [their documentation](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Attribute%20routing%20in%20Web%20API) on Scenario 3

There is also some answers on Stack Overflow like:

[How to handle hierarchical routes in ASP.NET Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783946/how-to-handle-hierarchical-routes-in-asp-net-web-api)

Answer (score 2):

There are solutions based on specifying route mappings but if you want more a more generic solution, [this](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/magical-web-api-action-selector-http-verb-and-action-name-dispatching-in-a-single-controller/) is by far the best solution I have seen related to this topic. Of course, Web API 2 has attribute routing.