# Swashbuckle in ASP.NET Web Api confused by nested controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

In my ASP.NET Web Api (ASP.NET 4 MVC 5) application I have two routes configured like so:

```
        // Default route. Comes "out of the box" with Web Api.
        // e.g. api/users/123
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // A route for child controllers. See for example the LockController 
        // that is "nested" under the "UsersController".
        // e.g. api/users/123/lock
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ChildApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{parentController}/{parentId}/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

These actually work quite well in that I have a "top level" `UsersController` that is matched by the first route and a "child" `LockController` (in a `Users` folder) that is matched by the second route.

Now that I've added [Swashbuckle 5](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) ([Swagger](http://swagger.io/) for .net) to my application, Swagger is confused into showing both routes for each method I've implemented. For example:

[image]

So Swagger recognizes the `LockController` as both a top-level controller and a child controller.

How can I tell Swagger that a particular controller is top-level or child?

Additionally, can I make swagger recognize that the path to the lock resource, for example, is `/api/users/{id}/lock` and not   `/api/{parentController}/{parentId}/lock` as Swagger is currently showing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783946/how-to-handle-hierarchical-routes-in-asp-net-web-api

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly where I got my routes from. Thing is, I want to keep using these generic routes, rather than specific routes that explicitly mention the parent controller name. I'm aiming for convention over configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is not related with inheritance hierarchy. Swashbuckle generates routes for every route mapping. To prevent Swashbuckle to generate duplicate routes , one solution could be adding controller constraint to routes.I hope this helps.

```
          config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { controller = "Users" }
        );

          config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ChildApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{parentController}/{parentId}/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { controller = "Lock" }

        );
```

Comment: Thanks. Definitely a step forward. Trying to think how to have something like this with more convention and less configuration.

Comment: maybe you should write your own custom constraint.!?

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work -

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("childapi", 
     "api/{Parent}/{i}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Works fine for -

```
http://localhost:60953/api/Another/1/Child/GetFlag/poo

http://localhost:60953/api/Parent/1/Child/GetFlag/poo

http://localhost:60953/api/Child/1/Another/GetString/test
```

Comment: This obviously does not work. There's no principle difference from the route I mentioned in the question. Swagger is still showing duplicate methods.