# C# REST API, Children of model should be of same type, and routes must be recursively defined

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, routes

Hi I am having an architectural problem with .NET Core

I have a controller called SContent with this route ->

```
[Route("api/content")]
```

- if you enter this route /api/content/ You will get all contents where Id is Guid.Empty;
- if you enter this route /api/content/{id} You will get a specific content from the first level of contents (MasterId must be equal to Guid.Empty in this case)
- if you enter this route /api/content/{id}/children you will get all children of the parent {id}

now what I want to do is to create a recursive Route for any of the following cases:

```
/api/content/{id}/children/{id2}
/api/content/{id}/children/{id2}/children
/api/content/{id}/children/{id2}/children/{id3}
```

and so on and so on...

is it possible to do something like that?
- children are of the same type of parent
- {id(N)} should always be a child of {id(N-1)}

Thanks

Comment: For each different route like `/api/content/{id}/children/{id2}/children`, you have to create a function containing parameters id. id2. If you want to create new route `/api/content/{id}/children/{id2}/children/{id3}`, you have to create a new function containing parameters id, id2, id3. So, I think, you can't implement recurse here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle hierarchical routes in ASP.NET Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783946/how-to-handle-hierarchical-routes-in-asp-net-web-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that there is no built-in route that can meet your needs . However, writing a custom middleware is easy .

short answer :

1. write a predicate which will set `Context.Items["Ids"]` and `Context.Items["WantChildren"]`
2. pass the predicate to a `MapWhen()` method .
3. write a middleware that will deal with logic to show content or get it's children according to `Context.Items["Ids"]` and `Context.Items["WantChildren"]`.

#### Quick and Dirty Demo

Here's a quick and dirty demo :

```
app.MapWhen(
    context =>{
        var path=context.Request.Path.ToString().ToLower();
        if (path.EndsWith("/")) {
            path = path.Substring(0, path.Length-1);
        }
        if (!path.StartsWith("/api/content")) {
            return false;
        }
        var ids = new List<int>();
        var wantChildren = false;
        var match= Regex.Match(path,"/(?<id>\\d+)(?<children>/children)?");
        while (match.Success) {
            var id = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups["id"].Value);  // todo: if throws an exception  , ...
            wantChildren= !String.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups["children"].Value);
            ids.Add(id);
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
        context.Items["Ids"] = ids;
        context.Items["WantChildren"] = wantChildren;
        return true;
    },
    appBuilder => {
        appBuilder.Run(async context =>{
            var ids = (List<int>)(context.Items["Ids"]);
            var wantChildren = (bool)(context.Items["WantChildren"]);

            // just a demo 
            // the code below should be replaced with those that you do with id list and whether you should display children
            foreach (var id in ids) {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(id.ToString());
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(",");
            }
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(wantChildren.ToString());
        });
    }
);
```

here's a screenshot that works [image: test-recursive-path]

#### Futher Refactoring

For better maintence , you can extract `Ids` and `WantChildren` to a single Class , for intance , `ContentChildrenContext` :

```
public class  ContentChildrenContext{
    public List<int> Ids {get;set;}
    public bool WantChildren{get;set;}
}
```

you can also make abstraction around the middleware itself , for example, create a factory method which returns a RequestDelegate that can be used easily with `app.Run()`:

```
Func<Func<ContentChildrenContext,Task>,RequestDelegate> CreateContentChildrenMiddleware(Func<ContentChildrenContext,Task> action){
    return async content =>{
        var ccc= (ContentChildrenContext)(context.Items["ContentChildrenContext"]);
        await action(ccc);
    };
}
```

Best Regards .