# Backbone nested collection url example

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have been reading [this article](http://liquidmedia.ca/blog/2011/01/backbone-js-part-1/) and the nested collection section sets the url as follows:

*'donut_shops/' + this.id + '/donuts'*

I am wondering how this would map to a web api controller and action etc. i.e. what would donut_shops/5/donuts call on a controller? I could understand if the id was at the end then it would be calling the donuts action passing in the id but I am confused with the id being in the middle.

```
var DonutShop = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults : {
  name : "Untitled"
},

initialize : function() {
// When you extend a Backbone.Model and give it an initialize function,
// the function is called when you instantiate an instance of your Model.

// The initialize function is used repeatedly in Backbone's prototypes. We'll be seeing this again
this.donuts = new Donuts;
this.donuts.url = 'donut_shops/' + this.id + "/donuts";
  }
});
```

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 0):

Nesting in this manner accesses the embedded collections of the base resource. So in this case, there are many `donut_shops` and each has many `donuts`. So with this URL:

```
'/donut_shops/5/donuts'
```

you `GET` all the `donuts` of the `donut_shop` which has an `id` of 5.

Answer (score 0):

`donuts_shops` is a collection of shops

`donuts_shops/5` is the shop with id 5

`donuts_shops/5/donuts` is a collection if donuts in the shop with id 5

`donuts_shops/donuts` is a collection of **all** donuts in **all** shops

`donuts_shops/5/donuts/6` is the donut with id 6 in the shop with id 5

Comment: Thanks for your answers and apologies for a late reply, I understand what data will be returned i.e. donuts from donut shop 5 etc. But I am not sure how this will be implemented with a Web API call. For example I assume there would be a donut_shop controller which accepts an integer for it's id, this would return donut_shop 5 but what method in the Web API would be called to get that shopts donuts? Is this all made with one call to the Web API?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I have found the answer to my question in this question posted a while ago on stackoverflow:

[nested resources in ASP.net MVC 4 WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594671/nested-resources-in-asp-net-mvc-4-webapi)

I suppose half the skill is in knowing what you are searching for :-)